# Time and date to variables

Tags: java, android

Hoping this is a simple one.

I need to set some variables to hold the selected values from my time picker and spinner.

Currently I'm trying to set the picked time using the 'Time' object but im getting an error that my arguments don't match those of the constructor:

Current code:

```
//Error on the constructor.
Time setTime = new Time(dobHour, dobMinute);
```

My second issue is that I'm trying to set the selected option from my spinner to a variable. Can someone tell me how I can set the selected spinner item to a variable (so i can insert it into my database).

As shown:

```
\\I realize this is the wrong format. Could someone 
\\tell me what I need to set it as?
String typeToSet =  setType.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the selected spinner item to a variable this way:

```
fve_txt = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fvetxt);
String spinVal = fve_txt.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

To set time you can do this :

```
Time time = new Time();
time.set(second, minute, hour, monthDay, month, year);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering your second question first... if setType is your Spinner then you want to `setType.getSelectedItem().toString();`

As to your second question [Time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) doesn't appear to have a constructor that takes just an hour and a minute (and the one that takes hour, minute, second) is deprecated.

Where are you getting these values? Depending on what they are there are various ways to get a Date object that reflects that moment in time.

I would probably go with [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then use its `set` method to move it to the date that you want.
however, again, without more detail as to what you're actually trying to do here, it's hard to offer meaningful advice.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error on the Constructor because it is wrongly used. [According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Time.html#Time%28int,%20int,%20int%29), you need three parameters for it (hours, minutes and seconds). Try:

```
Time setTime = new Time(dobHour, dobMinute, 0);
```

Keep in mind that this constructor is deprecated now, and you should be passing a millisecond value instead of individual ones.

To convert your hours and minutes into milliseconds try:

```
long milli = (dobHour * 1000 * 60 * 60) + (dobMinute * 1000 * 60) + 0;
```

Also, assuming `setType` is your spinner, you must use

```
String typeToSet =  setType.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

instead of

```
String typeToSet =  setType.getText().toString();
```